# Python : communication with c++ command line program not working when using <cstdio>

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, iostream, stdio

I have the following python code, which is supposed to provide the intial input to a C++ program, then take its output and feed it back into it, until the program finishes execution:

## comm.py

```
p = subprocess.Popen('test__1.exe', bufsize=1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=False)
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdout.flush()
x = b'1\n'
while True:
    p.stdin.write(x)
    p.stdin.flush()
    p.stdout.flush()
    x = p.stdout.readline()
    print(x)
    if p.poll() != None:
        break
```

I am currently testing it with two simple C++ programs:

## test__1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        cout << n+1 << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## test__2.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", n+1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When **comm.py** opens **test__1.exe** everything works fine, but when it opens **test__2.exe** it hangs on the first call to **readline()**.
Note that this problem does not occur when I feed **test__2.exe** the whole input before execution (i.e. initially set **x = '1\n2\n3\n'**)

What could be causing this issue?

(Also, comm.py should be able to handle any valid C++ program, so only using iostream would not be an acceptable solution.)

EDIT: I also need the solution to work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by the fact that `std::endl` flushes the `ostream` and `printf` does not flush `stdout`,
as you can see by amending `test__2.cpp` as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", n+1);
        fflush(stdout);  //<-- add this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You say that you want to module to work correctly with any C++ program, so
you can't rely upon it flushing the standard output (or standard error)
after every write.

That means you must cause the program's standard streams to be *unbuffered*
and do so *externally* to the program itself. You will need to do that
in `comm.py`.

In Linux (or other host providing GNU Core Utils), you could so by
executing the program via `stdbuf`, e.g.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['/usr/bin/stdbuf', '-i0','-o0', '-e0', './test__2']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=False)
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdout.flush()
x = b'1\n'
while True:
    p.stdin.write(x)
    x = p.stdout.readline()
    print(x)
    if p.poll() != None:
        break
```

which unbuffers all the standard streams. For Windows, you will need
to research how do the same thing. For the time being I don't know.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem, as I need comm.py to work with any valid C++ program.
On flushing the ostream, why doesnt the line:
    p.stdout.flush()
do the same?

Comment: @black-goat Yes I was pondering that and still am. See update.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Sadly I forgot to mention that I need it to work on Windows as well, but I will try to find an analogue to your suggestion.