# Looking for equivalent Windows command (to a Linux command for unbuffered console output)

Tags: python, linux, windows, cmd, stdout

This is a short python script, which is supposed to run the console application test__2 with unbuffered output.

## comm.py

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['/usr/bin/stdbuf', '-i0','-o0', '-e0', './test__2']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=False)
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdout.flush()
x = b'1\n'
while True:
    p.stdin.write(x)
    x = p.stdout.readline()
    print(x)
    if p.poll() != None:
        break
```

I need a equivalent to this line:

```
cmd = ['/usr/bin/stdbuf', '-i0','-o0', '-e0', './test__2']
```

which will run on Windows.

(For more context you can see [Python : communication with c++ command line program not working when using <cstdio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660740/python-communication-with-c-command-line-program-not-working-when-using-cst) )

Comment: Since you are not using `stderr` here would redirecting `stdout` to `stderr` be valid solution? `stderr` is always guaranteed to be unbuffered.

Comment: And if that doesn't work there is always option of running script with additional `-u` option like `python -u script.py`, you can read about this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota How do I redirect stdout to stderr?

Comment: `import sys; sys.stdout = sys.stderr` If you also do other stuff in this program you should save reference to `stdout` for later use.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota this does not work as I am redirecting the file's stdout and stderr. ( p.stdout = p.stderr does not work either )

Comment: There is no equivalent to Linux `stdbuf` on Windows. It's using the loader's `LD_PRELOAD` hook, which loads "libstdbuf.so" into the process, which calls `setvbuf` to configure the standard I/O buffering. Calling the latter is possible because POSIX systems have a global symbol table. The Windows loader doesn't have a hook like `LD_PRELOAD`, but you could start suspended, inject a DLL, and resume. The bigger problem is calling `setvbuf` in all possible C runtime DLLs (e.g. msvcrt.dll, msvcr100.dll, ucrtbase.dll, plus debug versions, etc) *after* they're loaded.

Comment: @eryksun So is there any way I can force an application to have unbuffered I/O on windows?

Comment: The child process may not buffer the output if you leave `stdin=None`, i.e. keep it set to the console input. If that's the case, instead of using a pipe you could write directly to the console input buffer using [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687403).

Comment: That's assuming `test__2` is a toy example, and you don't control the source of the real executable. If you do control the source, then obviously you can call `setvbuf` to disable buffering.

Comment: @eryksun WriteConsoleInput is a C++ function though. Does it have a Python equivalent?

Comment: @eryksun I do not control the other program. Technically it needs to be compatible with any valid C/C++ program (see thread linked at the bottom)

Comment: It's a C function, not C++. Anyway, you can either call it using ctypes (or cffi or cython, a C extension module, etc) or PyWin32's [`WriteConsoleInput`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/PyConsoleScreenBuffer__WriteConsoleInput_meth.html) method.